tmux renders duplicate lines in split pane divider
I'm randomly seeing duplicate lines on my split pane dividers that cut off the text in the pane. This only happens when there is a terminal window in the pane (not vim), often when I newline a couple of times, on my Ubuntu server (not locally).
Does anyone have any suggested fixes for this?

Info:

iTerm2 3.5.4
tmux version 3.4
Ubuntu 24.04 LTS

# remap prefix from 'C-b' to 'C-a'
# unbind C-b
set-option -g prefix C-a
set-option -g prefix2 C-b
bind-key C-a send-prefix

# split panes using | and -
bind | split-window -h
bind - split-window -v
# unbind '"'
# unbind %

# switch panes using Alt-arrow without prefix
bind -n M-Left select-pane -L
bind -n M-Right select-pane -R
bind -n M-Up select-pane -U
bind -n M-Down select-pane -D

# don't rename windows automatically
set-option -g allow-rename off

# clear window
bind -n C-k clear-history

# smart pane switching with awareness of vim splits
bind -n C-h run "(tmux display-message -p '#{pane_current_command}' | grep -iq vim && tmux send-keys C-h) || tmux select-pane -L"
bind -n C-j run "(tmux display-message -p '#{pane_current_command}' | grep -iq vim && tmux send-keys C-j) || tmux select-pane -D"
bind -n C-k run "(tmux display-message -p '#{pane_current_command}' | grep -iq vim && tmux send-keys C-k) || tmux select-pane -U"
bind -n C-l run "(tmux display-message -p '#{pane_current_command}' | grep -iq vim && tmux send-keys C-l) || tmux select-pane -R"

# Allow mouse control
set -g mouse on

# Fix vim theme issue
# https://github.com/mhartington/oceanic-next/issues/51
set -g default-terminal "xterm-256color"
set -g terminal-overrides ",xterm-256color:Tc"

set-option -g default-shell /bin/zsh

